# Spectron with mocha and chai does not work

Tags: testing, electron, mocha.js, chai, spectron

I am trying to write a tests with Spectron for our Electron App, but I am running into problems with the setup. I use the classical setup with chai. I have one file which contains setup code:

```
const path = require("path");
const { Application } = require("spectron");

module.exports = {
  initialiseSpectron: () => {
    let electronPath = path.join(__dirname, "../../node_modules", ".bin", "electron");

    if (process.platform == "win32") {
      electronPath += ".cmd";
    }

    return new Application({
      path: electronPath,
      args: [path.join(__dirname, "../index.ts"), path.join(__dirname, "../../package.json")],
      env: {
        ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING: true,
        ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING: true,
        NODE_ENV: "development"
      },
      startTimeout: 10000,
      chromeDriverLogPath: "../chromedriverlog.txt"
    });
  },
  sleep: time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
};
```

And then the test itself:

```
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
const chai = require("chai");
chai.should();
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

const testHelper = require("./initialise");
const app = testHelper.initialiseSpectron();

// Setup Promises and start Application
before(() => app.start());

// Tear down App after Tests are finished
after(() => {
  if (app && app.isRunning()) {
    return app.stop();
  }
});

describe("Login", () => {
  it("opens a window", function() {
    return app.client
      .waitUntilWindowLoaded()
      .getWindowCount()
      .should.eventually.equal(1);
  });

  it("tests the title", () =>
    app.client
      .waitUntilWindowLoaded()
      .getTitle()
      .should.eventually.equal("VIPFY"));
});
```

My problem is that I always get this error:

```
 1) "before all" hook in "{root}"

  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) "before all" hook in "{root}":
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

So it looks like the App does not start. But that is not true. The App Window opens, but it seems like the test does not recognize that. I have already tried changing the path using all kinds of syntax. But nothing worked. What am I missing?

Comment: Okay, the problem seems to be that we use an old version of electron which is not compatible with the version of spectron

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase the timeout for mocha?

Sometimes I had it fail first time, then worked on the second try.

See a working sample here with Electron 6:

https://github.com/florin05/electron-spectron-example

Comment: At this point, I basically tried everything. Will need some time before I give it a next try.